# What is $v(t)$ in a sliding conducting rail in a magnetic field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

This is problem 7.7c from David J. Griffiths - Introduction to Electrodynamics.

> A metal bar of mass $m$ slides frictionlessly on two parallel conducting
>   rails a distance $l$ apart. A resistor $R$ is connected across the rails, and a uniform magnetic field $B$, pointing into the page, fills the entire region.
>
> The force on the bar is $F = \frac{B^2l^2v}{R}$ (to the left).
>
> If the bar starts out with speed $v_0$ (to the right as in the figure) at time $t = 0$, and is left to slide, what is its
>   speed at a later time $t$?

The correct solution is:

$\frac{dv}{dt} = -\frac{B^2l^2v}{Rm} \Rightarrow v = v_0e^{-\frac{B^2l^2t}{Rm}}$

But my initial solution was: $v = v_0 - \frac{B^2l^2vt}{Rm} \Rightarrow v = \frac{v_0}{1+\frac{B^2l^2t}{Rm}}$

I think the formula $v = v_0 + at$ is only valid when acceleration is constant. That is where my error lies. Right?

Comment: Yes, that formula holds only for constant acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you're using is only valid when the acceleration of the body is constant.

You can read up more [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion) to understand why this is so. Simply put it's because of our assumption of constant acceleration that we end with the result you're using otherwise you'll get a differential equation.

In this question the force keeps on changing hence the acceleration also keeps changing.

To get the correct answer as mentioned in the book you need to write a differential equation for the velocity.

You can do this by writing your acceleration as

dV/dt

As it is rate of change of velocity
You'll end up with a fairly simple differential equation and by taking the antilog on both sides you'll get your answer.